# DTOs in a three tier Entity Framework application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, architecture, dto

I am building two C# three-tier applications that get their data a very old database Customer table that has about 100 columns. They perform some logic in the business layer and a presentation layer displays the data.

The layout of the customer table is -

```
CustomerID
Firstname
Lastname
DateOfBirth
Othervalue1
Othervalue2
Othervalue3
.
.
Othervalue95
Creationdate
Updatedate
```

For these two applications I only need the customer table, but I am building the a new data access layer with Entity Framework. Future projects will need  access to other tables and will add to this access layer.

I will use the Unit of work and repository patters.

My problem is the following -

**Application A** needs one subset of the customer table columns

and

**Application B** needs a different subset of the customer table columns (there is some overlap with Application A's needs)

How do I perform mapping from the data layer to these two independent business layers? I know I can use automapper to perform mapping from an data entity class to a business layer class, but I will have two different business layer Customer classes.

I have been reading a bit about DTO's but I don't see where there should go in this n-tiered application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use any of these based on your application design 
1 - Map customer table to two or more Entities 
2 - Have a base entity like CustomerBase and 2 or more sub entities. 
3 - DTOs are Data Transfer Objects and they are (normally) mutable.  Changing them wont result a CRUD operation on the DB.
 DTOs are used in scenarios like: Customer entity is a heavyweight object(say 100 columns) and you just need a subset of that data (say 20 columns).
 Conversion between the DTO object and the actual Entity could be implemented in many ways like auto-mapper, manually operator oveloading and more ...

Hope this helps

Comment: My Business layer already a lightweight Customer. And the data layer has the heavy weight Customer, where should the code for the DTO's live?

Comment: In presentaion layer you have a presenter(like a windows Form that must show some detailed information about Customer containing his name and number ... and his CreditScore(some other entity) and his last 10 Orders) so you will need a DetailedCustomerDTO, filling it some other entities data and sending it to Use Interface.

Comment: In some other scenario application A will call a service of application B (using Remoting,WebService, RPC or els) sending customerNumber to application B and requesting only customer full name and address and email so having a SimpleCustomerDTO will be usefull.

Answer (score 1):

Heres what I would do:

In Application A - extract the data you need, and map them to a new class (a DTO)
Do the same with Application B.

If the two applications have no other relation, than sharing af database, you should do nothing else. that is: keep Application A unawer of the existence og Application B, and vice versa.

The DTO is just a fancy name for the object you share across an n-tier application.

Comment: In which layer should I put the DTO? I don't think it can go in the data layer, that would mean two DTO's (one for App A and on for App B)

Comment: well, that depends. Perhaps you need many DTO's. Given your senario, you might want the DTO between the Data-tier, and you Bizz-Tier to be the entities them self. 
In your Bizz-tier you then map to a new DTO - shared by Bizz-tier and Presentation-tier

Answer (score 1):

You could use IOC and inject the relevant mapper into your data layer.

Do you need to use UoW and repository pattern?
EF is a data access abstraction with unit of work in its own right. You could access DBContext in your business layer and use Linq to project data into DTOs.

Comment: If I add DBContext to my business layer, won't I be programming to an implementation and couple the business and data layers? 
Like the suggestion of using IoC to inject the mapper.

Comment: Yes not ideal but i struggle with repositories on top of normalised relational dbs, and often end up with an IQueryable somewhere anyway! The IoC solution should work fine for you though. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need read only access on the legacy system?

In this case I suggest to use an [Anti Corruption Layer pattern](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2009/07/07/domain-driven-design-anti-corruption-layer/) on each applications and two distinct entity framework models where you can map only the required columns.

If you need also to write it is probably difficult, you must map all the columns.

If you want to use a single entity framework model then you can use dtos to map a subset of data. In this case auto mapper can be a good solution.

Comment: Will read about the Anti Corruption layer. Regarding the use of DTO's - where should they live in my tiers?

Comment: @tom they are domain classes so they live in the domain layer. I usually create a xyz.domain assembly with the entities definitions, dtos, enums and repository interfaces (or other base service interfaces).

Comment: If I put the DTO in the domain layer, will the data layer  have to reference the domain layer? If so, won't that couple the two layers?

Comment: @tom Yes, with a domain driven design the application layer and the data access layer (that contains the repository implementation) reference the domain model layer. At runtime the dependency between data access and domain is inverted thanks to the inversion of control pattern.